# Access Control Lists vs. chmod for proper nginx permissions in /var/www

Tags: linux, nginx, permissions, debian, file-permissions

On our server, I work with another developer. We want to both be able to edit files, make files, etc. We both want to be able to edit each other's files and be in complete collaboration with each other with no permission errors or having to use sudo all the time. We are also using Git. We have had issues in the past with Git making weird database files with the root username or group or only one of us. Then when we try to push to the repository, we get crazy errors and have to chmod everything back to one of us so the author is unified. Just a general mess. We are using a debian server.

1. Should we make 2 usernames and add them to the www-data group? Is adding us to www-data and having people visit the website secure with that?
2. Should we then chmod all folders to 755 permission and files to 644?
3. We want all new files made within /var/www to be in one of our usernames but with the www-data group by default so that we can both edit the file. Is the chmod -R g+rws /var/www enough for this? We want files to be ready as soon as they are made. File permissions set properly by default.
4. Should we use ACL for this instead of all the chmod stuff?

Is this a good guide to follow?
http://machiine.com/2013/easy-way-to-give-user-permission-to-edit-and-add-files-in-varwww/

Thanks

Comment: for questions about server-administration, please use [sf]